# How to calculate hyperplane for SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am using SVM for document categorization. For that I have training sets i.e. set of training vector with their category. For example I have following sample data(assumption):

```
   -1 1:1 2:1
   +1 2:1 4:1
   -1 3:1 5:1
   +1 1:1 6:1
```

Can any one say:
  1) How to plot the data points in vector space(Sample diagram for the given test data   will help me best)?
  2) How to calculate**hyperplane** using the given sample?. 
  3) How to classify the new document using hyperlane for following data?

```
       2:1 4:1
```

4)Whether the kernel function are used for generating hypherlane efficiently?

---

```
My sample data:
-1 3:1 11:1 14:1 19:1 39:1 42:1 55:1 64:1 67:1 73:1 75:1 76:1 80:1 83:1 
-1 3:1 6:1 17:1 27:1 35:1 40:1 57:1 63:1 69:1 73:1 74:1 76:1 81:1 103:1 
-1 4:1 6:1 15:1 21:1 35:1 40:1 57:1 63:1 67:1 73:1 74:1 77:1 80:1 83:1 
-1 5:1 6:1 15:1 22:1 36:1 41:1 47:1 66:1 67:1 72:1 74:1 76:1 80:1 83:1 
-1 2:1 6:1 16:1 22:1 36:1 40:1 54:1 63:1 67:1 73:1 75:1 76:1 80:1 83:1 
-1 2:1 6:1 14:1 20:1 37:1 41:1 47:1 64:1 67:1 73:1 74:1 76:1 82:1 83:1 
-1 1:1 6:1 14:1 22:1 36:1 42:1 49:1 64:1 67:1 72:1 74:1 77:1 80:1 83:1 
-1 1:1 6:1 17:1 19:1 39:1 42:1 53:1 64:1 67:1 73:1 74:1 76:1 80:1 83:1 
-1 2:1 6:1 18:1 20:1 37:1 42:1 48:1 64:1 71:1 73:1 74:1 76:1 81:1 83:1 
+1 5:1 11:1 15:1 32:1 39:1 40:1 52:1 63:1 67:1 73:1 74:1 76:1 78:1 83:1 
-1 5:1 16:1 30:1 35:1 41:1 64:1 67:1 73:1 74:1 76:1 80:1 83:1 
-1 5:1 6:1 15:1 20:1 37:1 40:1 50:1 63:1 67:1 73:1 75:1 76:1 80:1 83:1 
-1 5:1 7:1 16:1 29:1 39:1 40:1 48:1 63:1 67:1 73:1 74:1 76:1 78:1 83:1 
-1 1:1 11:1 18:1 20:1 37:1 42:1 59:1 62:1 71:1 72:1 74:1 76:1 80:1 83:1 
+1 5:1 18:1 19:1 39:1 40:1 63:1 67:1 73:1 74:1 76:1 80:1 83:1
```

```
My Sample model file content:
1.0 3:1.0 11:1.0 14:1.0 19:1.0 39:1.0 42:1.0 55:1.0 64:1.0 67:1.0 73:1.0 75:1.0 76:1.0 80:1.0 83:1.0 
1.0 4:1.0 6:1.0 15:1.0 21:1.0 35:1.0 40:1.0 57:1.0 63:1.0 67:1.0 73:1.0 74:1.0 77:1.0 80:1.0 83:1.0 
1.0 2:1.0 6:1.0 16:1.0 22:1.0 36:1.0 40:1.0 54:1.0 63:1.0 67:1.0 73:1.0 75:1.0 76:1.0 80:1.0 83:1.0 
1.0 5:1.0 6:1.0 15:1.0 20:1.0 37:1.0 40:1.0 50:1.0 63:1.0 67:1.0 73:1.0 75:1.0 76:1.0 80:1.0 83:1.0 
1.0 5:1.0 7:1.0 16:1.0 29:1.0 39:1.0 40:1.0 48:1.0 63:1.0 67:1.0 73:1.0 74:1.0 76:1.0 78:1.0 83:1.0 
0.47854266714671057 2:1.0 11:1.0 18:1.0 20:1.0 37:1.0 40:1.0 54:1.0 63:1.0 67:1.0 73:1.0 74:1.0 76:1.0 80:1.0 83:1.0 
1.0 2:1.0 6:1.0 15:1.0 19:1.0 39:1.0 40:1.0 52:1.0 63:1.0 67:1.0 73:1.0 74:1.0 76:1.0 82:1.0 83:1.0 
1.0 3:1.0 6:1.0 14:1.0 22:1.0 36:1.0 40:1.0 54:1.0 63:1.0 67:1.0 73:1.0 74:1.0 76:1.0 80:1.0 83:1.0 
1.0 5:1.0 8:1.0 14:1.0 19:1.0 39:1.0 40:1.0 50:1.0 63:1.0 67:1.0 73:1.0 74:1.0 76:1.0 82:1.0 83:1.0 
0.26128743031116053 3:1.0 7:1.0 18:1.0 22:1.0 36:1.0 40:1.0 50:1.0 63:1.0 67:1.0 73:1.0 74:1.0 76:1.0 82:1.0 83:1.0 
1.0 5:1.0 15:1.0 22:1.0 36:1.0 40:1.0 63:1.0 67:1.0 73:1.0 74:1.0 76:1.0 82:1.0 83:1.0 
1.0 1:1.0 15:1.0 21:1.0 35:1.0 45:1.0 62:1.0 68:1.0 72:1.0 74:1.0 77:1.0 80:1.0 93:1.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have more than two (in this example you have five, to be precise) dimensions, plotting would hardly help. Finding the maximum-margin separating plane is exactly what SVM is for. Unless you intend to implement it yourself, I suggest that you run [LIBSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) on your data and read the resulting model file, which will contain the support vector coordinates. I'm not sure how to get the separating hyperplane out of that, but even if you do, it'll only be a hyperplane in the kernel space, not in the one where your samples are. If you just want to do linear classification, it may be better to use [LIBLINEAR](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) instead -- it's input format is the same as that of LIBSVM.

The decoding (i.e. predicting the class for a new sample) can be done either by invoking the corresponding binary from the distribution.

Comment: Hi Qnan.. I have tested LIBSVM with some sample data given in site.. I got model created by LIBSVM trainer. I have updated my question with sample training data and model created.. Can you please highlight which one is hyperplane coordinate?

Comment: @vigneshkumarrathakumar see the edit.

Comment: I believe if you have just two classes, then after running LIBSVM will contain a column of weights `w` that specify the hyperplane. The classification then should be something like comparing the dot product of that vector with a feature vector of a new sample and comparing that to zero.